# UTF-8, digits and regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, utf-8, kohana, kohana-3

This is what I've found in the Kohana3 validator rules:

```
public static function digit($str, $utf8 = FALSE)
{
    if ($utf8 === TRUE)
    {
        return (bool) preg_match('/^\pN++$/uD', $str);
    }
    else
    {
        return (is_int($str) AND $str >= 0) OR ctype_digit($str);
    }
}
```

Can someone give an example when passing `$utf8` parameter as `true` and `false` can give different results (to be precise - false positives for `$utf8 == false`)?

From what I remember - digits are ascii-safe characters and none of utf-8 characters may be confused with them.

**PS**: even more detailed - is it possible to fool this check and pass something that in UTF-8 would look not like a number, but would pass the check with `$utf-8 == false`

Comment: @mario: it's obvious for invalid UTF-8, but I'm curious about valid one. Like the famous sql escaping "vulnerability" with quote and multibyte charset, but with digits

Comment: Just tested, PCRE rejects an invalid UTF-8 encoding anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just gave your second question part a bit more alcohol, and my conclusion is that you can't hide an ASCII digit in a UTF-8 sequence. Digits must be `0x30`..`0x39` or in the bitrange `00110000`..`00110110`..`00111001`.

UTF-8 encodings include prefixes such as

```
 11110xxx  10xxxxxx  10xxxxxx
```

And therefore a digit ASCII representation can't match anywhere:

```
 00110000 
 ▲▲        00110000  ▼
           ▲         00110000
```

So it's impossible that it would match in Latin-1/ASCII mode, but also have `\pN` satisfied  in `/u` mode. Ignoring invalid encodings of course.

Answer (score 3):

Even though 0-9 are ASCII safe, there's a lot of other numbers in Unicode.

See [Unicode Characters in the 'Number, Decimal Digit' Category](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm)
 for a list. Some examples are U+0660 ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT ZERO (٠) and U+1D7EC MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF BOLD DIGIT ZERO ().

Comment: These are examples of false negatives. Thanks for that. But any false positives? (when `$utf-8 == true` would give false and `$utf-8 == false` would give true)

Answer (score 1):

1. [Aegean Numbers](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U10100.pdf),
2. [Ancient Greek Numbers](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U10140.pdf),

...etc.

Comment: Any thoughts about `PS` in the question?

Comment: @zerkms - Without unicode regex modifier `/u` you cannot use `\pN`, as this is a valid identifier just in unicode extension. In unicode regex `\pN` matches all `\d` and all other non-ascii number characters. In non-unicode regex you can use just `\d` for digits, when all non-ascii number characters will not match...

Comment: I didn't say anything about removing `u` modifier, I've asked if it's possible to compose a valid UTF-8 string that would look like not a set of digits but will be validated successfully with `$utf8` parameter `== false`

Comment: @zerkms - I believe regex works independently. If you use `\pN` with `\u` modifier, you should get same results, regardless of `$utf8`.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're continuing discussing `/u` :-S "you should get same results, regardless of $utf8" - "should" ;-)